# K largest elements in an array

Tags: c++, array

I solve problems to prepare for interviews. Now I have written the algorithm of finding K largest numbers in array. Various solutions are described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/. Initially, I came up with the solution myself and looks my solution corresponds to that described as **Method 2** on the site, with the difference that I additionally use the "old minimum" to cut off unnecessary steps along the nested loop.

What could be written better in my code? What could be used instead of `pmin`?

Here is my implementation:

```
using namespace std;

vector<int> largest_part_of_vector(const vector<int>& vec, int K_PartSize)
{
    assert(K_PartSize < vec.size());

    vector<int> ret(K_PartSize);

    // Initial filling of temporary vector
    int ind = 0; // main end-to-end index
    int* pmin = const_cast<int*>(&vec[0]); // current minimum
    // How `pmin` could be declared and used better?

    for (auto& elemRef : ret)
    {
        elemRef = vec[ind];

        if (elemRef < *pmin)
        {
            pmin = &elemRef; // pmin is from `vecPart` now and will not modify `vec`
        }

        ind++;
    }

    // the rest part
    auto oldMin = *pmin;
    for (; ind < vec.size(); ind++)
    {
        auto v = vec[ind];

        if (v > oldMin) // preliminary check to avoid unnecessary checks
        {
            for (auto& elemRef : ret)
            {
                if (elemRef < *pmin)
                {
                    pmin = &elemRef;
                }
            }

            if (v > * pmin)
            {
                oldMin = *pmin;
                *pmin = v;
            }
        }
        /*else
        {
            savedIterations++;
        }*/
    }

    return ret; // As I understand, moving operator=( vector&& other ) will be used here
}
```

Comment: Of course, the real answer to such an interview question is to just call `std::partial_sort_copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using namespace std;` is poor practice - don't do that.

`K_PartSize` should probably be a `std::size_t`.

`assert()` is not a good way to validate arguments - it's intended for making claims about invariants in the logic.  It won't be present in non-debug builds, and when it is present, it can abort the program, without running destructors or any other cleanup.

Instead, implement some useful behaviour:

```
if (!partsize) {
    return {};
}
if (partsize >= vec.size()) {
    return vec;
}
```

I dislike the `const_cast` for `pmin`.  I think it would be better to construct `ret` from the beginning part of the input vector, and start `pmin` pointing to the first element of that:

```
std::vector<int> ret(vec.begin(), vec.begin()+partsize);
int* pmin = &ret[0];
```

I'd suggest that this would be better as an iterator than a pointer:

```
auto pmin = ret.begin();
```

I'd swap round the test of `(v > oldMin)`:

```
if (v <= oldMin) {
    continue;
}
for (auto& elemRef : ret)
```

I don't think we need both `pmin` and `oldMin`, certainly if we use the standard `min_element` algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> largest_part_of_vector(const std::vector<int>& vec, std::size_t partsize)
{
    if (!partsize) {
        return {};
    }
    if (partsize >= vec.size()) {
        return vec;
    }

    std::vector<int> ret(vec.begin(), vec.begin()+partsize);
    auto pmin = std::min_element(ret.begin(), ret.end());

    // the rest part
    for (auto ind = vec.begin() + ret.size();  ind != vec.end();  ++ind)
    {
        auto const v = *ind;

        if (v <= *pmin) { continue; }

        *pmin = v;
        pmin = std::min_element(ret.begin(), ret.end());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Test program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename V>
class printable_vector
{
    V const& v;
public:
    explicit printable_vector(const V& v) : v{v} {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const printable_vector& p) {
        os << '{';
        char const* sep = "";
        for (auto const& e: p.v) {
            os << sep << e;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        return os << '}';
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto const a = std::vector{ 1, 2, 12, 3, 2, 6 };

    for (auto k: {0, 1, 4, 5, 9}) {
        std::cout << printable_vector{largest_part_of_vector(a, k)} << '\n';
    }
}
```